# varchar column returning exponential representation of number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `varchar(max)` column that sometimes returns me the exponential format of the number like so:

```
1e+006
```

How do I alter the column in the table to always have it show me the actual number and not an exponential representation of the number?

I would alter the column to a different data type or something, but I have no idea what I'd alter it to, since I don't understand why this is happening in a `varchar` column.

Comment: Why are you storing a number as varchar?  What types of numbers are you storing?

Comment: Seems you also have a bug in the process that stores this information.

Comment: A) What process or query is creating the number in the first place? B) As far as determining the data type, what is the value supposed to represent (total number of widgets, a percentage, etc...)? Are there any known restrictions on the value?

Comment: Exactly *when* did that value get changed? On *read* or on *write*? (if it is a varchar value, I expect the transformation on *write*)

Comment: @devlincarnate I have a python script where I'm using a to_sql() function to write the information out to the database, for some reason it's classifying that column as a varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A varchar like '1e+006' can be converted to `float`, which can then be further converted to any numeric type you like.

So this might be as simple as

```
alter table mytable alter column mycolumn float
```

perhaps followed by a conversion to a decimal type:

```
alter table mytable alter column mycolumn decimal(20,5)
```

Comment: From my understanding this column will contain integers, I see that you said to alter the column to a float type first and then to another data type if I wish. What is the reason that I couldn't/wouldn't want to convert straight to a column with integer type? Data loss? Just curious thank you!

Comment: SQL Server just won't allow you to convert that string directly to an integer.  IE `cast('1e+006' as integer)` fails.